# Ant exec shell script - loses environment

Tags: shell, ant

I am trying to exec a shell script like so in Ant:

```
<exec executable="bash" newenvironment="false" dir="./">
  <arg value="script.sh">
</exec>
```

But when it executes the script, all references to environment variables such as $MY_VARIABLE come back as the empty string. How do I get around this? According to http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html I believe the environment should be propogated. (I also realize newenvironment defaults to false.)

Edit: I see the env element, but I don't see a way to pass the environment in en masse. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: where is MY_VARIABLE defined?

Comment: As an environment variable... The question is how can I make a subprocess see the environment, i.e. when Runtime.exec is called underneath the covers it is not having the environment passed to it. Passing each item in is not feasible, as I am trying to write something simple and extensible.

Answer (score 4):

Have you exported the variable?  Sub-processes will not see the variable unless you export it:

```
$ cat a.xml
<project>
  <exec executable="bash" newenvironment="false" dir=".">
    <arg value="script.sh"/>
  </exec>
</project>
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
env
$ MY_VARIABLE=defined
$ ant -f a.xml | grep MY_VARIABLE
$ export MY_VARIABLE
$ ant -f a.xml | grep MY_VARIABLE
     [exec] MY_VARIABLE=defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, that executes a new bash shell (with whatever config and new environment are defined for your active user) and then the bash shell takes the arguments and executes.

Might try the following to execute in the current shell environment

```
<exec executable="script.sh" newenvironment="false" dir="./">
</exec>
```